# How to do a lot of deep copies (Python)

Tags: python, copy

I just found out how to make a deep copy of an array in python with the copy() command. Now I would like to find out how I can do several copies from the same array without wasting lots of lines of code

**My original code (too long)**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([3])
b = np.zeros([3])
c = np.zeros([3])
d = np.zeros([3])
e = np.zeros([3])
f = np.zeros([3])
```

**Deep independant copies (still to long)**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([3])
b=a.copy()
c=a.copy()
d=a.copy()
e=a.copy()
f=a.copy()
```

**How can I do several deep copies with less commands? (Following command does shallow copies :P...)**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([])
b = c = d = e = f = a.copy()
```

Comment: `from numpy import copy as cp;a=np.zeros([3]);b=cp(a);c=cp(a);d=cp(a);e=cp(a);f=cp(a)` How about this? you wanted less lines right?

Comment: Thank you SilverSlash for the fast answer. The copy command works fine for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a loop + list comprehension for that:

```python
a, b, c, d, e, f = list(np.zeros([3]) for _ in range(6))
```

Comment: Hello mistiru, this solution is even more elegant ! Thanks a lot :)